# Custom WordPress Walker - Advice Needed

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a walker in WordPress that will display categories in a particular structure. I'm fairly new to PHP/WordPress Walkers so I need some input as to whether a walker is the most suitable option for my needs and any code examples you can provide.

The structure I'd like to create is as follows:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="normal-link"<a href="/">Home</a>
    <li class="parent-category">
        <a href="#">Parent Category</a>
        <div class="sub-categories">
            <span>Parent Category</span>
            <ul class="sub-nav">
                <li class="subcategory">Subcategory 1</li>
                <li class="subcategory">Subcategory 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="normal-link"><a href="/about">About Us</a>
    <li class="normal-link"><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
</ul>
```

The above structure will allow me to place page links (that I hard code into my menu) together with parent category links in a top level menu. I'll then be making the sub-categories div a dropdown which will show the parent category name in a span followed by a list of all subcategories belonging to that parent.

My problem is that I'm not looking to use the Appearance>Menu's section of WordPress. Instead, I'm looking to create a menu that's hard-coded in my header.php file. My main reason for this is so that any new categories I add will automatically be shown if they have posts assigned to it. From my understanding, If I were to use the Appearance>Menus section inside WP Admin then I'd have to enter the menu and add any new categories each time I create them.

From the above, I'm not sure how to tackle the fact that I need to show only some "Pages" (home, about, contact) but show all "Categories" that have posts (and in the format as shown in my code.)

Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks,
James

Comment: Yup, only way of achieving this is a custom category walker. Try reading this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115194/adding-ul-class-with-wp-list-categories-custom-walker

Comment: Thanks Sergiu. I'm making progress with this now. Thanks for your help. I'll post the completed walker when I have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody looking to achieve this, I've created my walker using the code below. I've changed some of the class names from my example menu structure above, added a class to the span and added the category slug as a class to each parent list element (so I can style each parent and its children with different colours etc).

```
class Navigation_Catwalker extends Walker_Category {

// Configure the start of each level
function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $output .= "";
}

// Configure the end of each level
function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $output .= "";
}

// Configure the start of each element
function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {

    // Set the category name and slug as a variables for later use
    $cat_name = esc_attr( $category->name );
    $cat_name = apply_filters( 'list_cats', $cat_name, $category );
    $cat_slug = esc_attr( $category->slug );

    // Configure the output for the top list element and its URL
    if ( $depth === 0 ) {
        $link = '<a class="parent-category-dropdown" href="' . esc_url( get_term_link($category) ) . '"' . '>' . $cat_name . '</a>';
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\t<li class='parent-category " . $cat_slug . "'>$link\n<div class='category-dropdown'>\n<span class='parent-category-title'>" . $cat_name . "</span>\n$indent<ul class='submenu'>\n";
    }

    // Configure the output for lower level list elements and their URL's
    if ( $depth > 0 ) {
        $link = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link($category) ) . '"' . '>' . $cat_name . '</a>';
        $output .= "\t<li class='sub-category'>$link\n";
    }

}

// Configure the end of each element
function end_el(&$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    if ( $depth === 0 ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n</div>\n";
    }
    if ( $depth > 0 ) {
        $output .= "</li>";
    }

}

}
```